# Minify the JSON Output from OpenSearch

Tags: json, minify, opensearch

Is it possible to minify the JSON Output of OpenSearch? Currently it sends all the useless spaces with each request. I have already filtered the elements I want to query, but would love to even save a bit more bandwidth on the client-side.
That's my current request:

```
{
        "_source": ["highlight", "current_page_name", "title", "base_url", "doc_url", "doc_type", "doc_title"],
        "query": {
            "multi_match": {
              "query": val,
              "type": "best_fields",
              "operator": "and",
              "fields": [ "body", "title^2" ]
            }
        },
        "highlight": {
            "number_of_fragments": 1,
            "fragment_size":100,
            "pre_tags": [
                "<span style='color: var(--color-green)'>"
            ],
            "post_tags": [
                "</span>"
            ],
            "fields":{
                "body": {},
                "title": {}
            },
            "require_field_match" : false
        }
    };
```